# OkHttp Websockets - Add a body when connecting to websocket

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

I am using the okHttp websocket library and I am successfully connecting to my websocket server, but currently I am only getting the connection id when connected. I want to send some extra info in the body, but I don't know how to add it using okHttp

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("wss://mywebsocketurl.com")
                .build();
```

I have tried

```
RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder()
.add("camera_id", "e9502c54-927c-4639-a94f-8d03149c9c62")
.build();


Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("wss://mywebsocketurl.com")
                .method("POST", requestBody)
                .build();


Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("wss://mywebsocketurl.com")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
```

But it keeps returning

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method GET must not have a request body.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to answer.
The url should anyways be GET only. So i made the connection and on onOpen callback function, i send the body. It worked.

```
private fun initializeSocket(url: String) {
    val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val listener = WebSocketListener()
    webSocket = client!!.newWebSocket(request, listener)
    client?.dispatcher()?.executorService()?.shutdown()
}

private class WebSocketListener : WebSocketListener() {
    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response?) {
        val content = "{\n" +
                "  \"messageType\": \"INIT_CONNECTION\"\n" +
                "}"
        webSocket.send(content)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This only works if the server you connect to does not require a body immediatelly on connect..